# Rolling count of processes linux

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line, process

Is there a way to get a rolling count of the number of processes running, especially of tasks which match a specific string?

Something like `top | grep TaskName | wc -l`

Comment: What about `ps -e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

`watch -n 1 'pgrep -c TaskName'`

Comment: Great, if there was a way to stop it from taking up the entire screen that would be aesthetically better, but this is exactly the functionality I want!

Comment: Not that I'm aware of ... `watch` doesn't have any means to limit the output size, it utilises the full terminal.